# Cordova and Bower/Polymer Error

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, bower

I can't run and build my Cordova app while Polymer is installed via Bower.

At first I created my project via Cordova, and added Android as a platform.

I then initialized bower in my "www" directory in my app, and tried to run the app. There were no errors.

But when I add Polymer/polymer + Polymer/core-elements and Polymer/paper-elements as components via Bower, I'm getting this error:

```
    -package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.npmignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.travis.yml' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.json' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
     [aapt]     (skipping file '.bower.js

BUILD FAILED
D:\Android Studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Android Studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: -1073741819

Total time: 30 seconds

D:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: D:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\MyProject\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Can anyone help me? This error only shows when Polymer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/ant/build.xml` and override the following parameter:

```
<property name="aapt.ignore.assets" value="" />
```

With new values, ignoring `.*.`

But instead of playing around with the build files, I would suggest that you create a new cordova project, **copy** your code to www and remove all .bower.json and .gitignore files. Here are the commands to do so:

> find . -type f -name ".*" -exec rm {} \;

You also need to unzip any already zipped file and need to run:

> find . -type f -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} \;

Or better yet, use hard links. This way you would not have to copy the files again.